# jQuery: I need to select element's background property when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery, when clicking on this `.team-member` container...

```
<div class="team-member">
    <div class="team-img team-one"></div>
</div>
```

...I would like to grab the background url that is set to `.team-one` ...

```
.team-one {
    background: url("../media/team-one.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This is as far as I got, which returns the correct class but I can't go further. Is it even possible to grab an element's background property this way or do I need to do something else?

```
$(".member").click(function(member) {
    console.log(member.currentTarget.children[0].children[0].classList[1])
})
```

Comment: You mean to get the css class name?

Comment: @MariosNikolaou I am trying to get the background image url that is assigned to that class name

Comment: Once you have the element, you can do something like `$('.team-one').css('background')`

Comment: @Prokzy its backgroundImage

Comment: @EvikGhazarian that is true, `'background'` would return the whole background property like `url("../media/team-one.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50%`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with jQuery. Use child and each to loop through all the children (if needed). and get the `backgroundImage`

```js
$(".team-member").click(function() {
    $(this).children().each(function () {
    var background = $(this).css("backgroundImage"); // this gets the background of each child
    var className = $(this).attr("class"); // this gets the class list of each child (if needed)
    $(".result").append(className + " background URL is: " + background + "<br/>");
});
}) ;
```

```css
.team-one {
    margin-top: 15px;
    background: url("../media/team-one.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}
.team-two {
    background: url("../media/team-two.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}
.team-three {
    background: url("../media/team-three.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}
.team-member {
    background: url("../media/team-member.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}
.result {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="team-member">
Team Member
    <div class="team-img team-one">Team one</div>
    <div class="team-img team-two">Team two</div>
    <div class="team-img team-three">Team three</div>
</div>
<div class="result">

</div>
```

**NOTE:** You want the function to run on click of the `.team-member` but your selector is `member`.

> **IF YOU ONLY NEED TEAM ONE (OR SPECIFIC CLASS) BACKGROUND SEE BELOW:**

```js
$(".team-member").click(function() {
    var background = $(".team-one").css("backgroundImage"); //gets background of team-one
    var className = $(".team-one").attr("class"); //gets classes of team-one
    $(".result").append(className + " background URL is: " + background + "<br/>");
}) ;
```

```css
.team-one {
    margin-top: 15px;
    background: url("../media/team-one.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}
.result {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="team-member">
Team Member
    <div class="team-img team-one">Team one</div>
</div>
<div class="result">

</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for. I just made a mistake by typing member instead of team-member

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".team-member").click(function(){
const backGround = $(this).closest(".team-one").attr('style').split(";")[0];
console.log(backGround);
});
```

```html
<div class="team-img team-one" style="background: url("../media/team-one.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
background-size: cover;"></div>
```